# Unable to open the html file in eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse

I just imported a project in eclipse juno , there are various html files in that project all other html files are opening except one . I have checked the code, everything is fine in that file . New to eclipse! Any help is highly appreciated . Thanks in advance.
.log file :

```
  !SESSION 2017-08-25 17:32:04.979 -----------------------------------------
  ------
  eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
  java.version=1.8.0_91
  java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
  BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
  Framework arguments:  -product 
  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
  Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product 
  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct

  !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2017-08-25 17:32:24.842
  !MESSAGE Invalid property category path: ValidationPropertiesPage (bundle: 
  org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui, propertyPage: 
  org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.propertyPage.project.validation)
   !SESSION 2017-08-25 17:32:26.662 ----------------------------------------
   -------
  eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
  java.version=1.8.0_91
  java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
  BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
  Framework arguments:  -product 
  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
  Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product 
  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct

  !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2017-08-25 17:59:43.538
  !MESSAGE Invalid property category path: ValidationPropertiesPage (bundle: 
  org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui, propertyPage: 
  org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.propertyPage.project.validation)
```

Comment: What happens instead of it being opened? None of us have the file in question nor access to your error logs.

Comment: Nothing, the screen remains blank! No errors

Comment: From outside of Eclipse, look for your workspace's `.metadata/.log` file.

Comment: What should I look for in it? It's there ....

Comment: Stack traces or other messages that coincide with the files not opening. Which you should then share here.

Comment: edited, please have a look.

Comment: Your Eclipse is pretty old (more than 4 years). Could you reproduce your issue with the [latest version of Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/)?

Comment: Your installation looks broken, even if that just part of your `.log` file. If you're going to use the latest Java Runtime, it makes sense to use as recent an Eclipse release.